# Почему Visual studio перестала показывать подсказку для автозаполнения кода?

Tags: unity3d

раньше вводил системный метод "OnCollisionEnter" в unity
сразу выходила подсказка для автозаполнения(автоопределения) метода с телом и параметрами
Сейчас нету её
Что могло повлиять?
В других скриптах всё нормально Всплывает окно с названием метода
А вэтом Как будто VS воспринимает его как поле...
Может это изза атрибута [SerializedField]?

Answer (score 0):

Я в шоке!
Прям магия какя то
Я закомментировал //[SerializeField] private int _health;
поменял на public раскоментировал (не помогло)
поставил всё как было [SerializeField] private int _health;
И о чудо!
Заработало

Comment: для вас совет, ставьте своим вопросам дополнительно тег `c#`, тогда будет больше вероятность, что вам ответят.